# How to return a table variable from a function (UDF)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and I have been trying lots of different approaches to return a table variable from inside a function, but I cannot get it to work. I've tried moving the variable declaration to different places, etc. Here are the guts of the sql. If you could please wrap the guts in a UDF function that actually compiles and returns the @Financials table variable I would appreciate it. The sql works great, no problems. But when I try to wrap it in a UDF it throws errors when I try to create it. I hardcoded some stuff to make it easier to test and visualize.

```
DECLARE @Financials TABLE (
    [a bunch of variable declarations in here]
);

insert into @Financials
[big old SELECT query here - this all works fine, and populates @Financials]

    select * 
    from @Financials f1
    where f1.TransactionDate = (
        select MAX(TransactionDate)
        from @Financials
        where SalesDocumentItemID = f1.SalesDocumentItemID
    )
```

I need the UDF to return @Financials now.

If this is impossible, please consider my real problem, which is shown in the select * from @Financials above, in which I want to match only the latest TransactionDate, joined by SalesDocumentItemID. If I could find an efficient way to do this, I wouldn't need to do the INSERT into @Financials at all. I guess the problem is that the query that populates @Financials is complex, with lots of joins, and I don't want to duplicate all of it again in the subselect. But I'm guessing there's an awesome and easier way to do that. Would love some ideas.

Comment: Are you trying to make that function permanently available on the database?

Comment: Yes, a permanent UDF. But I'm open to other options.

Comment: What errors is it throwing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't use `DECLARE` when returning a table variable.  Define the result table in the `RETURNS` clause.

```
CREATE Function GetFinancials ()
RETURNS @financials TABLE
(
  [a bunch of variable declarations in here]
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into @Financials
    [big old SELECT query here - this all works fine, and populates @Financials]

    RETURN
END
```

### Update

How about returning the final result in a stored procedure?

```
create procedure uspGetFinanicals
as
  declare @financial table
  (
    [table definition here]
  )

  insert into @financial
  select dbo.GetFinancials()

  select * 
    from @Financials f1
    where f1.TransactionDate = (
        select MAX(TransactionDate)
        from @Financials
        where SalesDocumentItemID = f1.SalesDocumentItemID
    )
```

### Update

Try this.  Create a table variable within the UDF to store the results of the first select, then insert the result of the final query into the return value.

```
CREATE Function GetFinancials ()
RETURNS @financials TABLE
(
  [a bunch of variable declarations in here]
)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @table table([a bunch of variable declarations in here])
    insert into @table
    [big old SELECT query here - this all works fine, and populates @Financials]

    insert into @Financials
    select * 
      from @table f1
      where f1.TransactionDate = (
        select MAX(TransactionDate)
        from @table
        where SalesDocumentItemID = f1.SalesDocumentItemID
      )

    RETURN
END
```

Comment: you've gotten me really close, but I'm getting 1 error now: "Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client." It's complaining about that final SELECT statement with a subselect at the very end. How can I solve?

Comment: @SweatCoder Correct - no selects allowed. To make the subset you need, you'll have to either restrict the data inserted into '@financials' or delete the extra data once it's inserted (the former being comparatively less expensive).

Comment: Hey Sweat, you can't return a table with a stored procedure.

Comment: This should be the solution. Nice Jerrad.

Comment: It needs to be a function because many procs already do selects against it, like SELECT * FROM Financials(1,2,3). This Financials UDF already exists, I just need to change the sql inside as indicated, and that's what's not working.

Comment: @Jerrad, I don't think a proc will work because I have to SELECT against the UDF directly. Procs don't work that way.

Comment: Sweat, you're gonna have to post your code. At least the section causing the error.

Comment: Can't the insertion simply be restricted to that subset?

Comment: @SweatCoder, make it another UDF instead of a proc?