# How to eliminate rows based on MAX(TransactionDate)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a complex query with lots of columns in the select, and many joins. The 2 main tables (not the only ones) are SalesDocumentItems and Transactions. I only want records with unique SalesDocumentItemIDs and I'm willing to achieve this by only joining with the matching Transactions record with MAX(TransactionDate). Here's an example:

```
select * 
from @Financials f1
where f1.TransactionDate = (
    select MAX(TransactionDate)
    from @Financials
    where SalesDocumentItemID = f1.SalesDocumentItemID
)
```

That query actually works perfectly and does exactly what I need, but populating @Financials inside a UDF has proven impossible for me to achieve. In fact I have another stack question open on that topic:

[How to return a table variable from a function (UDF)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436609/how-to-return-a-table-variable-from-a-function-udf)

Regardless of the outcome of the other posted question, I'd still love to know how to do this without resorting to a table variable. I also think GROUP BY is not a good option because there are TONS of columns in the select and tons of joins and it just seems too hairy to go that route.

** EDIT BELOW **

I am including my original select statement. I really need a little help on how to integrate the approaches you guys have shown into my current query. Not sure how to connect the two. Many thanks.

```
Select [a bunch of columns, including SalesDocumentItemID and TransactionDate]

    From
        (   Select [a bunch of Transaction columns]
            From Transactions trx_detail
            Where trx_detail.TransactionStatusID = 1
                and trx_detail.TransactionDate >= @StartDate
                and trx_detail.TransactionDate < DATEADD(dd,1,@EndDate) 
        ) t
        inner join gym.Account acct on t.AccountID = acct.AccountID
        inner join gym.SalesDocumentItemTransaction linker on linker.TransactionId = t.TransactionID    --do not need to aggregate because there is only ever one set of sales docs items when looking from the transaction's perspective
        inner join gym.SalesDocumentItems docitems on linker.SalesDocumentItemID = docitems.SalesDocumentItemID
        inner join gym.Product prod on docitems.ProductID = prod.ProductID
        left join gym.ProductGroup pgroup on prod.ProductGroupID = pgroup.ProductGroupID
        left join gym.RevenueGroup rgroup on pgroup.RevenueGroupID = rgroup.RevenueGroupID
        left join gym.[Site] home on acct.SiteID = home.SiteID
        left join gym.[Person] collector on t.CollectorPersonID = collector.PersonID
        left join gym.[Registration] reg on reg.RegistrationID = t.RegistrationID
        left join gym.[Site] trx_site on trx_site.SiteID = reg.SiteID
        left join gym.TransactionStatus tstatus on t.TransactionStatusID = tstatus.TransactionStatusID
Where (@SiteID = 0 OR (@SiteID <> 0 and docitems.RevenueSiteID = @SiteID))
```

Data example:

```
SalesDocumentID  TransactionDate
1020557          2014-06-25 16:44:01.930
1020557          2014-06-25 16:44:17.557
1020557          2014-06-25 16:44:33.210
1020558          2014-06-25 16:44:50.007
1020558          2014-06-25 16:44:33.210
1020559          2014-06-25 16:44:50.007
```

Here is my final, non-compiling query based on advice from Blam:

```
select tjoin.*
    from (
      Select t.SalesDocumentItemID, t.TransactionDate, SeqNum=row_number() 
        over (partition by t.SalesDocumentItemID 
        order by t2.TransactionDate desc)
        From
        (   --Filter Transactions First for optimization purposes, prior to joining to the linker table
            Select
        --Transaction Information
        t.TransactionID
        ,t.AccountID
        ,t.AccountContractID
        ,t.SalesDocumentID
        ,docitems.SalesDocumentItemID
        ,t.CollectorPersonID
        ,trx_site.SiteID as CollectedSiteID
        ,t.SalesPersonID
        ,t.PaymentMethodID
        ,t.CCnumber
        ,t.TransactionStatusID
        ,t.TransactionDate
        ,t.TransactionAmount
        ,t.APIResponseCode
        ,t.APIResponseReason
        ,t.RegistrationID
        ,t.TransactionTypeID
        ,year(t.TransactionDate) as TransactionYear
        ,month(t.TransactionDate) as TransactionMonth
        ,datepart(ww, t.TransactionDate) as TransactionWeek
        ,day(t.TransactionDate) as TransactionDay

        --Trx Type Breakdown TransactionTypeID  Name; 1 BillingProcess; 2   POS; 3  PaymentOnAccount; 4 Refund
        ,case when t.TransactionTypeID = 1 then linker.Amount else 0 end as BillingProcess
        ,case when t.TransactionTypeID = 2 then linker.Amount else 0 end as PointOfSale
        ,case when t.TransactionTypeID = 3 then linker.Amount else 0 end as PaymentOnAccount
        ,case when t.TransactionTypeID = 4 then linker.Amount else 0 end as Refund

        ,linker.Amount as LineItemAmount

        --Product Information
        ,docitems.ProductID 
        ,docitems.Amount 
        ,docitems.Quantity 
        ,docitems.TaxAmount 
        ,docitems.TotalAmount 
        ,docitems.AmountPaid
        ,docitems.RevenueSiteID
        ,prod.ProductName
        ,prod.ProductGroupID
        ,pgroup.ProductGroup
        ,pgroup.RevenueGroupID --added for new available field 17 May 2014
        ,rgroup.RevenueGroup 

        --Account Info (Home Site for non-inventoried products filter - read: repetitives)
        ,acct.IsActive
        ,acct.SiteID
        ,home.SiteName

        --Collector Info
        ,gym.Person__FormatName(collector.FirstName, collector.LastName, collector.MiddleName, collector.NickName) as CollectorName

        --Collected Site Info (Sale Site for inventoried products filter - read: merchandise)
        ,trx_site.SiteName as CollectedSiteName

        --Transaction Status Info
        ,tstatus.Name as TransactionStatus  

    From
        (   --Filter Transactions First for optimization purposes, prior to joining to the linker table
            Select
                trx_detail.TransactionID
                ,trx_detail.AccountID
                ,trx_detail.AccountContractID
                ,trx_detail.SalesDocumentID
                ,trx_detail.CollectorPersonID
                ,trx_detail.SalesPersonID
                ,trx_detail.PaymentMethodID
                ,trx_detail.TransactionStatusID
                ,trx_detail.TransactionDate
                ,trx_detail.TransactionAmount
                ,trx_detail.APIResponseCode
                ,trx_detail.APIResponseReason
                ,trx_detail.TransactionTypeID
                ,trx_detail.RegistrationID
                ,trx_detail.CCNumber
            From
                gym.[Transaction] trx_detail
            Where
                trx_detail.TransactionStatusID = 1  --successful transactions only
                and trx_detail.TransactionDate >= @StartDate
                and trx_detail.TransactionDate < DATEADD(dd,1,@EndDate) --need to add 1 day to account for the Time portion of the TransactionDate.  Notice it is simply Less Than (no equal).
        ) t
        inner join gym.Account acct on t.AccountID = acct.AccountID
        inner join gym.SalesDocumentItemTransaction linker on linker.TransactionId = t.TransactionID    --do not need to aggregate because there is only ever one set of sales docs items when looking from the transaction's perspective
        inner join gym.SalesDocumentItems docitems on linker.SalesDocumentItemID = docitems.SalesDocumentItemID
        inner join gym.Product prod on docitems.ProductID = prod.ProductID
        left join gym.ProductGroup pgroup on prod.ProductGroupID = pgroup.ProductGroupID
        left join gym.RevenueGroup rgroup on pgroup.RevenueGroupID = rgroup.RevenueGroupID
        left join gym.[Site] home on acct.SiteID = home.SiteID
        left join gym.[Person] collector on t.CollectorPersonID = collector.PersonID
        left join gym.[Registration] reg on reg.RegistrationID = t.RegistrationID
        left join gym.[Site] trx_site on trx_site.SiteID = reg.SiteID
        left join gym.TransactionStatus tstatus on t.TransactionStatusID = tstatus.TransactionStatusID

    Where (@SiteID = 0 OR (@SiteID <> 0 and docitems.RevenueSiteID = @SiteID))) tjoin
  where tjoin.SeqNum = 1
```

Comment: Why are you using a UDF?  It looks like it just does a select statement.

Comment: The UDF is because many other stored procs need to query directly against this query - to avoid tons of duplication.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a staging table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for returning a table 
[How do I "Declare the scalar variable" in a VIEW in Sql Server (2005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475712/how-do-i-declare-the-scalar-variable-in-a-view-in-sql-server-2005)

Why do you feel you need a table variable?
I assume the two table are SalesDocumentItems and Transactions

```
select tjoin.*
from (  select *, SeqNum=row_number() over (partition by t1.SalesDocumentItemID 
                                                order by t2.TransactionDate desc)
          from SalesDocumentItems t1 
          join Transactions t2
            on t1.SalesDocumentItemID = t2.SalesDocumentItemID
     ) tjoin
where tjoin.SeqNum = 1
```

If SalesDocumentItems is really a complex query then just use a cte

```
WITH SalesDocumentItems (SalesDocumentItemID, TransactionDate, ...)
AS
(
    SELECT ...
)
    select tjoin.*
    from (  select *, SeqNum=row_number() over (partition by t1.SalesDocumentItemID 
                                                    order by t2.TransactionDate desc)
              from SalesDocumentItems t1 
              join Transactions t2
                on t1.SalesDocumentItemID = t2.SalesDocumentItemID
         ) tjoin
    where tjoin.SeqNum = 1
```

You are making this way harder than it needs to be

```
select tjoin.*
    from (
      Select t.SalesDocumentItemID, tTransactionDate
           , SeqNum=row_number() over (partition by t.SalesDocumentItemID 
                                           order by t2.TransactionDate desc)
        From Transactions t
        inner join gym.Account acct 
           on t.AccountID = acct.AccountID
          and t.TransactionStatusID = 1
          and t.TransactionDate >= @StartDate
          and t.TransactionDate < DATEADD(dd,1,@EndDate)
        inner join gym.SalesDocumentItemTransaction linker 
           on linker.TransactionId = t.TransactionID    
        inner join gym.SalesDocumentItems docitems 
           on linker.SalesDocumentItemID = docitems.SalesDocumentItemID
        inner join gym.Product prod 
           on docitems.ProductID = prod.ProductID
          and (@SiteID = 0 OR docitems.RevenueSiteID = @SiteID)
         left ..... does note effect the core question
        inner join Transactions t2
           on t1.SalesDocumentItemID = t2.SalesDocumentItemID ) tjoin
  where tjoin.SeqNum = 1
```

Comment: I'm only using a table variable because I couldn't find a better way. Seeing some great options here though...trying them out now.

Comment: Please see my edited post and show how I can integrate your approach into my current query. Thanks.

Comment: Blam: I do apologize, but when I integrated what you said, it doesn't compile. Please look at my original post where I pasted my full SQL. What am I doing wrong at this point? Thanks again.

Comment: Finally got it. Thanks Blam.

Answer (score 2):

GROUP BY is not a bad thing if used correctly! Still, in this case, windowing functions is probably a better choice. This will get 1 record from Transactions for each SalesDocumentItemID:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t2.*, SeqNum=row_number() over (partition by SalesDocumentItemID order by SomeSensibleField)
    from Transactions t2
) t
where SeqNum = 1
```

Note the ORDER BY used with the row_number() function. You need to specify how to choose which record you want for each SalesDocumentItemID. E.g. if you want the most recent one, you could use "(partition by SalesDocumentID **order by SomeDateColumn desc**)" or whatever suits your needs.

Check out windowing functions more closely. They are VERY powerful.

Comment: The order by clause is mandatory for row_number. So it's misleading to say "if you want a specific record...".

Comment: One must always use ORDER BY in a window function however, Slims is right about the power of these.

Comment: Yep, you're right. ROW_NUMBER() requires some kind of ORDER BY. Many windowing functions do not however, e.g. `select f1, sum(f2) over (partition by f1) from (select f1='A', f2=2 union all select 'A', 2 union all select 'B', 3) t`

Comment: Nice, I wonder when that changed. I'm looking through the documentation now. I stand corrected! Still a bad idea to not use an order by (unless the column in the window is the clustered index), otherwise the results could vary between runs.

Comment: I need some clarification on how to integrate this approach with my existing query. Although the @Financials will be obsolete (replaced by a massive select statement with lots of joins), if you could use that in your example I'll know how to actually do this. Thanks!

Comment: Sweat - If you provide a couple examples of data in these tables, we could help you format the query. Otherwise, you will just have to jump off Slims answer (which I think is the best way to accomplish this)

Comment: @Nick: I provided data examples and my latest stab at the whole query. It doesn't compile. I think I'm really close, just need a little advice as to what I'm doing wrong.